# d3 graph tabulating from json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I made a graph and send it using json. Now I need to put all type, id and name attributes of graph into a table, that can be updated when new data will appear. The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var json = [{"multigraph": false, "directed": true, "links":
    [{"source": 2, "target": 0}, {"source": 2, "target": 1}, {"source": 2, "target": 3}, {"source": 2, "target": 4}],
    "graph": {}, "nodes":
    [{"id": "'(clear d)', '(ontable b)', '(ontable d)', '(ontable c)', '(clear b)', '(holding a)', '(clear c)'",
    "name": "'(clear d)', '(ontable b)', '(ontable d)', '(ontable c)', '(clear b)', '(holding a)', '(clear c)'",
    "type": "search_node"},
    {"id": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(clear d)', '(ontable c)', '(ontable d)', '(clear c)', '(holding b)'",
    "name": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(clear d)', '(ontable c)', '(ontable d)', '(clear c)', '(holding b)'",
    "type": "search_node"},
    {"id": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(ontable b)', '(clear d)', '(ontable d)', '(handempty)', '(ontable c)', '(clear c)', '(clear b)'",
    "name": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(ontable b)', '(clear d)', '(ontable d)', '(handempty)', '(ontable c)', '(clear c)', '(clear b)'",
    "type": "search_node"},
    {"id": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(ontable b)', '(holding d)', '(ontable c)', '(clear b)', '(clear c)'",
    "name": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(ontable b)', '(holding d)', '(ontable c)', '(clear b)', '(clear c)'",
    "type": "search_node"},
    {"id": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(clear d)', '(ontable b)', '(ontable d)', '(holding c)', '(clear b)'",
    "name": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(clear d)', '(ontable b)', '(ontable d)', '(holding c)', '(clear b)'",
    "type": "search_node"}]}]

    d3.json(json, function (error,data) {

  function tabulate(data, columns) {
        var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
        var thead = table.append('thead')
        var tbody = table.append('tbody');

        // append the header row
        thead.append('tr')
          .selectAll('th')
          .data(columns).enter()
          .append('th')
            .text(function (column) { return column; });

        // create a row for each object in the data
        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('tr');

        // create a cell in each row for each column
        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
          .data(function (row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
              return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
          })
          .enter()
          .append('td')
            .text(function (d) { return d.value; });

      return table;
    }

    // render the table(s)
    tabulate(data, ['type', 'id', 'name']);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Headers are appear but no information appear under them. I think the problem is with additional tags in json file. How I can present all the information from json file to table?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the json object, you can directly use it in d3 like this:

```
    var json = [{"multigraph": false, "directed": true, "links":
        [{"source": 2, "target": 0}, {"source": 2, "target": 1}, {"source": 2, "target": 3}, {"source": 2, "target": 4}],
        "graph": {}, "nodes":
        [{"id": "'(clear d)', '(ontable b)', '(ontable d)', '(ontable c)', '(clear b)', '(holding a)', '(clear c)'",
        "name": "'(clear d)', '(ontable b)', '(ontable d)', '(ontable c)', '(clear b)', '(holding a)', '(clear c)'",
        "type": "search_node"},
        {"id": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(clear d)', '(ontable c)', '(ontable d)', '(clear c)', '(holding b)'",
        "name": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(clear d)', '(ontable c)', '(ontable d)', '(clear c)', '(holding b)'",
        "type": "search_node"},
        {"id": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(ontable b)', '(clear d)', '(ontable d)', '(handempty)', '(ontable c)', '(clear c)', '(clear b)'",
        "name": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(ontable b)', '(clear d)', '(ontable d)', '(handempty)', '(ontable c)', '(clear c)', '(clear b)'",
        "type": "search_node"},
        {"id": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(ontable b)', '(holding d)', '(ontable c)', '(clear b)', '(clear c)'",
        "name": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(ontable b)', '(holding d)', '(ontable c)', '(clear b)', '(clear c)'",
        "type": "search_node"},
        {"id": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(clear d)', '(ontable b)', '(ontable d)', '(holding c)', '(clear b)'",
        "name": "'(ontable a)', '(clear a)', '(clear d)', '(ontable b)', '(ontable d)', '(holding c)', '(clear b)'",
        "type": "search_node"}]}]


      function tabulate(data, columns) {
            var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
            var thead = table.append('thead').append('th')
            var tbody = table.append('tbody');

            // append the header row
            thead.append('tr')
              .selectAll('th')
              .data(columns)
              .enter()
              .append('th')
              .text(function (column) { 
                return column; });
            // use the nodes from the json since they hold the information for the columns
            var nodes = data[0].nodes;
            // create a row for each object in the data
            var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
                                    .data(nodes)
                                .enter()
                                .append('tr')

            // create a cell in each row for each column
           var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
             .data(function(row) {
               return columns.map(function(column) {
                 return {
                   column: column,
                   value: row[column]
               };
             });
           })
         .enter()
         .append('td')
        .text(function(d, i, e) { // i == td
           return d.value;
         })


          return table;
        }
        // render the table(s)
        tabulate(json, ['type', 'id', 'name']);

Fi
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4b35qkg2/3/ 
I also changed the rows data to be the nodes of the json.

I hope this helps. 
Good luck!

Edit: To clarify, the problem was that by using `d3.json(json, function (error,data)` was trying to load the json from a location not from an object (`d3.json(json_file_path, function (error,data)`).

Comment: but it show only the second node all the time. Not all nodes

Comment: cell description need to be like:         `var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
            .data(function(row) {
                return columns.map(function(column) {
                    return {column: column, value: row[column]};
                });
            })
            .enter()
            .append("td")
            .attr("style", "font-family: Courier") // sets the font style
                .html(function(d) { return d.value; });`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4b35qkg2/3/ Yep! from here http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/473f0cf66196a008cf99